# How to erase some part of Texture with Rectangle?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a Texture that needed to be erase on some point of game. I think its best to clarify my question with picture.

Below is the actual texture.

[image]

It is place inside an actor and being call inside the draw after adding to stage.
Below is the partial code of the texture

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    batch.draw(trLine,position.x,position.y);

}
```

I wanted to erase some part of the texture using a Rectangle with x,y,width And height.And also its can be more than one time. How do I achieve this?

Added: I have found a article that use pixmap to load the texture and modifying it using mask. below is the code, but unfortunately , it draw nothing.

```
    Pixmap mask = new Pixmap(trLine.getRegionWidth(), trLine.getRegionWidth(), Pixmap.Format.Alpha);

    mask.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.None);
    mask.setColor(0,0,0,0);
    mask.fillRectangle((int)rec.x,(int)rec.y,(int)rec.width,(int)rec.height);

    Pixmap fg = new Pixmap(trLine.getRegionWidth(), trLine.getRegionWidth(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

    for (int x = 0; x < trLine.getRegionWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < trLine.getRegionHeight(); y++) {
            int colorInt = fg.getPixel(trLine.getRegionX() + x, trLine.getRegionY() + y);
            fg.drawPixel(colorInt,trLine.getRegionX() + x , trLine.getRegionY() + y);
        }
    }

    fg.drawPixmap(mask, fg.getWidth(), fg.getHeight());
    mask.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.SourceOver);

    trBlendedLine=new Texture(fg);
```

Comment: Since it's just a rectangular cutout, I think the best method of doing this for performance would be to calculate and draw 8 TextureRegions from your texture. This would have a trivial impact on performance even if you change the cutout size/position on every frame, whereas the Pixmap method would cause stuttering.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right , although the frame doesn't change frequently , I already notice a performance issue using pixmap